# checking an object in a nested link via dxl

Tags: ibm-doors

I have the following situation.
I want to count in Module 1, how many objects are having links in links from Module 3.

example:

Module 1 Obj1   <-  Module 2 Obj1   <- Module 3.Obj1

Module 1 Obj2   <-  Module 2 Obj1   <- Module 3.Obj1

Module 1 Obj3   <-  Module 2 Obj1   <- Module 3.Obj1

Module 1 Obj4   <-  Module 2 Obj1

Module 1 Obj5   <-  Module 2 Obj1

The count should return 3, in the above case.

Is it possible via DXL to follow a link, and then follow another link?
(not using the Wizard or DXL attributes)

Most important for me: knowing if somebody else did this and it's possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following DXL from within the module that has the incoming links. Before running the code:

1. make sure that you open the 'Edit DXL' window from the relevant module
2. set the string values assigned to global constant STR_LINK_MOD_FULLNAME (line 17) to the full pathname of the link module whose links you are interested in
3. set the string values assigned to global constant STR_SRC_MOD_FULLNAME (line 18) to the full pathname of the source formal module (Module 3, in your example) whose links you are interested in

You shouldn't need to change anything else to make it work.

N.B. I have not considered the implications of analysing links in all link modules by using the string "*" in place of a specific link module name in line 17 (see point 2, above).

I also haven't gone out of my way to explain the code, though I have tried to be nice and tidy up after myself where DOORS and DXL require it. Please feel free to reply with any questions on what I have done.

Kind regards,

Richard

```
//<CheckObjectInNestedLink.dxl>

/*
 */

///////////////
// Sanity check

if (null (current Module))
{
    print "ERROR: this script must be run from a Formal Module."
}

///////////////////
// Global Constants

const string STR_LINK_MOD_FULLNAME = "/New Family Car Project/Admin/Satisfies" // the fullName of a single link module - results of using "*" have not been considered/tested
const string STR_SRC_MOD_FULLNAME  = "/New Family Car Project/Architecture/Architectural Design" // The fullName of the desired source Formal Module


///////////////////
// Global Variables

Module modSource               = null
Object objTarget               = null
Object objSource               = null
Link   lkIn                    = null
Skip   skLinkedMods            = create()
Skip   skObjsWithDesiredSource = create()

int intNoOfLinked              = 0


//////////////////////
// Auxiliary Functions

void closeSourceMods ()
{
    Module srcMod

    for srcMod in skLinkedMods do
    {
        close(srcMod)
    }
}

void openSourceMods (Object objWithLinks)
{
    ModName_ srcModRef
    Module   srcMod

    for srcModRef in (objWithLinks <- STR_LINK_MOD_FULLNAME) do
    {
        srcMod = read(fullName(srcModRef), false)
        put(skLinkedMods, srcMod, srcMod)
    }
}

void recurseFollowInLinks (Object objWithLinks)
{
    openSourceMods(objWithLinks)

    for lkIn in objWithLinks <- STR_LINK_MOD_FULLNAME do
    {
            openSourceMods(objWithLinks)
            objSource = source(lkIn)

            string strSrcModName = fullName(module(objSource))

            if (strSrcModName == STR_SRC_MOD_FULLNAME)
            {
                bool blNewEntry = put(skObjsWithDesiredSource, objTarget, objTarget)

                if (blNewEntry)
                {
                    intNoOfLinked++
                }
                //print "put(skObjsWithDesiredSource, " identifier(objTarget) ", " identifier(objTarget) ")\n"
            }

            recurseFollowInLinks(objSource)
    }
}

void checkObjectInNestedLink (Module modThis, string strSourceModuleFullname, string strLinkModuleFullName)
{
    intNoOfLinked = 0

    for objTarget in modThis do
    {
        recurseFollowInLinks(objTarget)
    }

    print "The following " intNoOfLinked " objects have direct or indirect links of type " STR_LINK_MOD_FULLNAME " from formal module " STR_SRC_MOD_FULLNAME ":\n"

    for objTarget in skObjsWithDesiredSource do
    {
        print identifier(objTarget)
        print "\n"
    }
}


///////////////
// Main Program

checkObjectInNestedLink ((current Module), STR_SRC_MOD_FULLNAME, STR_LINK_MOD_FULLNAME)

closeSourceMods()
delete(skLinkedMods)
delete(skObjsWithDesiredSource)
```